# Pretty StackOverflow

Tags: script

This userscript provides a prettier interface to StackOverflow.

[(Click for larger image)
[image: Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWlJY.png)

### Installation

- [Stylebot page](http://stylebot.me/styles/4)
- [Userscript install link](http://stylebot.me/style/userscript/4.user.js)

It also hides notifications. To bring them back, you can remove the following CSS in the beginning:

```
#notify--1 {
 display: none;
}

#notify-2 {
 display: none;
}

#notify-container {
 display: none;
}
```

---

---

---

For reference, here is the complete CSS:

```css
#notify--1   {
   display:   none;
}

#notify-2   {
   display:   none;
}

#notify-container   {
   display:   none;
}

#hlinks-custom   a   {
   color:   #264780;
}

a.post-tag   {
   border-style:   solid;
   border-width:   1px;
   border-color:   #b6c2e3;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   font-size:   10px;
   color:   #374966;
   background-color:   #E0EAF1;
}

#nav-askquestion   {
   background-color:   #426685;
   border-radius:   2px;
   font-size:   14px;
}

.nav.askquestion   li   {
   background-color:   transparent;
}

div.nav.mainnavs   a   {
   background-color:   #e7eaf0;
   border-radius:   2px;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   font-size:   14px;
   padding-bottom:   7px;
   color:   #4d5f8a;
}

div.subheader   {
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   border-color:   #ccc;
   margin-bottom:   10px;
}

div.mini-counts   {
   font-size:   20px;
}

div.status.answered-accepted   {
   background-color:   #5da351;
   color:   #f1f2e4;
   border-color:   #5da351;
   border-style:   solid;
   border-width:   1px;
}

a.badge-tag   {
   border-radius:   0px;
   border-color:   #ccc;
   border-width:   1px;
   font-size:   11px;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
}

a.badge   {
   border-radius:   0px;
   background-color:   #5c5c5c;
   border-width:   1px;
   border-color:   #fff;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   font-size:   11px;
}

span.badge1   {
   height:   8px;
}

tr   td   a   {
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
}

img.sponsor-tag-img   {
   margin-top:   -2px;
   margin-left:   -3px;
}

div.status.answered   {
   background-color:   #dafccf;
   color:   #435c3b;
   border-color:   #a5db95;
   border-style:   solid;
   border-width:   1px;
}

div.votes   {
   border-color:   #a3a3a3;
   border-style:   solid;
   border-width:   1px;
}

div.status.unanswered   {
   color:   #e8e8e8;
   border-style:   solid;
   border-width:   1px;
   border-color:   #9A4444;
}

a.question-hyperlink   {
   line-height:   20px;
}

div.post-text   p   {
   font-family:   Helvetica,   Arial,   sans-serif;
}

div.question-summary.tagged-interesting   {
   background-color:   #e4eff7;
}

div.question-summary   {
   border-color:   #ccc;
   border-style:   solid;
}

div.status.answered   strong   {
   color:   #1e4711;
}

#tabs   a:hover   {
   border-color:   #ccc;
}

a.youarehere   {
   color:   #5878b8;
   border-color:   #ccc;
   border-top-width:   1px;
   border-right-width:   1px;
   border-left-width:   1px;
   border-bottom-width:   0;
   font-size:   14px;
}

div.question-summary.narrow   {
   padding-top:   15px;
   padding-bottom:   15px;
}

a.post-tag:hover   {
   background-color:   #6e819e;
   border-color:   #6e819e;
   color:   #fff;
}

div.status.answered-accepted   strong   {
   color:   #f1f2e4;
}

div.stats   {
   background-color:   transparent;
}

div.statsarrow   {
   display:   none;
}

#interestingAdd   {
   font-size:   10px;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   background-color:   #ebebeb;
   padding-left:   5px;
   padding-right:   5px;
   border-color:   #dbdbdb;
}

#ignoredAdd   {
   font-size:   10px;
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   background-color:   #ebebeb;
   padding-left:   5px;
   padding-right:   5px;
   border-color:   #dbdbdb;
}

#tag-menu   {
   border:   1px   solid   #ccc;
   font-size:   12px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:   none;
   display:   none;
}

#submit-button   {
   background-color:   #f2f2f2;
   color:   #333;
   padding:   4px;
   border-color:   #d1d1d1;
}

#submit-button:hover   {
   background-color:   #666666;
   color:   #fff;
}

div.bounty-indicator   {
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   border-radius:   0px;
   background-color:   #639dc7;
   font-size:   10px;
   line-height:   14px;
   border-width:   1px;
}

span.bounty-indicator-tab   {
   font-family:   "Lucida   Grande",   Verdana,   sans-serif;
   border-radius:   0px;
   background-color:   #639dc7;
   font-size:   10px;
   line-height:   14px;
   border-width:   1px;
}

div.nav.mainnavs   li.youarehere   a   {
   background-color:   #536c8a;
   color:   #fff;
}

div.everyonelovesstackoverflow   a   img   {
   display:   none;
}

div.question-summary.narrow.tagged-interesting   {
   background-color:   #edf5fc;
   padding:   15px   5px;
}

div.nav.mainnavs   li   {
   background-color:   transparent;
}

#recent-badges   span.badge2   {
   height:   9px;
}

#recent-badges   span.badge1   {
   height:   9px;
}

div.container   {
   margin-top:   -30px;
}

#custom-header   {
   margin-top:   -32px;
}
```

Comment: I added the screenshot for you :)

Comment: [Link](http://stylebot.me/style/get_userscript/4.user.js) not working

Comment: **WARNING!**  The userscript installed by that `stylebot.me` site **contains many malware links and iframes!**